# Embedded services using chain of responsibility?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I currently have a few "*worker services*" that wrap existing code to automate incredibly repetitive code. A few examples are:

- Method analytics.
- Iteration support.
- Exception logging.

My current setup requires me to wrap my code in layers:

```
AnalyticsService.Run((analyticsContext) => {
    IterationService.Run((iterationContext) => {
        ExceptionService.Run((exceptionContext) => {
            ...
            DoSomethingCool();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a big fan of this, as I have hundreds of methods that need to use these interchangeably. So, after some searching, and posting a question with an XY problem on Stack Overflow, a commenter pointed me in the direction of the chain of responsibility pattern.

I love the pattern, and it looked like it would fit well at first glance, so I wrote up a simple implementation to test it out:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testService = new AnalyticsService(new IterationService());
        testService.Process((context) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Comencing test.");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}");

            context.Exit();
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
internal interface IEmbeddableServiceContext
{
    void Exit();
}
internal sealed class EmbeddableServiceContext : IEmbeddableServiceContext
{
    public bool ShouldExit { get; private set; } = false;
    public void Exit() => ShouldExit = true;
}
internal abstract class EmbeddableService
{
    private EmbeddableService _embeddedService;
    public EmbeddableService() { }
    public EmbeddableService(EmbeddableService embeddedService) => _embeddedService = embeddedService;
    public void Process(Action<IEmbeddableServiceContext> request)
    {
        if (request == null)
            return;

        var context = new EmbeddableServiceContext();
        Execute(context, (embeddedContext) =>
        {
            if (_embeddedService != null)
                _embeddedService.Process(request);
            else
                request(context);
        });
    }
    protected abstract void Execute(EmbeddableServiceContext context, Action<IEmbeddableServiceContext> request);
}
internal sealed class AnalyticsService : EmbeddableService
{
    public AnalyticsService() { }
    public AnalyticsService(EmbeddableService embeddedService) : base(embeddedService) { }

    protected override void Execute(EmbeddableServiceContext context, Action<IEmbeddableServiceContext> request)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        request(context);
        Console.WriteLine($"Your request took {(DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds}ms to complete.");
    }
}
internal sealed class IterationService : EmbeddableService
{
    public IterationService() { }
    public IterationService(EmbeddableService embeddedService) : base(embeddedService) { }
    protected override void Execute(EmbeddableServiceContext context, Action<IEmbeddableServiceContext> request)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            request(context);
            if (context.ShouldExit)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest issue I have with this implementation is that the context models are now forced to be combined unless I want a maintenance nightmare. However, I wanted to get some feedback on the current implementation, before I take the next steps into further automating the developer implementation experience.

***NOTE**: Please don't mind the fact that everything is marked as `internal` here. That's a separate issue altogether.*

Comment: A very small tip: Using `bool ShouldExit` as flag controlling logic isn't a thing to do. In multithreaded/async environment you can catch some issues with that e.g. unpredictable behavior. Try `CancellationToken` instead.

Comment: Also just an idea to move: learn something about Rx.NET, looks like the above job can be done with Rx easily. In case Rx is overkill, the alternative idea is Fluent interfaces/extension Linq-like methods.

Comment: @aepot with regard to `ShouldExit`, that's actually allowing the caller to signal that the iteration service should stop iterating. In the original worker service for it, it's a method called `Break` with a property `ShouldBreak`. With regard to your second comment, thank you for the reading material :)

Comment: Then signal to stop is coming from another thread. Use thread-safe way to signal, bool isn't safe.

Comment: @aepot I see what you're saying now, sorry about that.